Advertising Test Beginning Nov 13 2024
We’ve been exploring the concept of using open auction to manage advertising on some Stack Exchange sites. Under this model, advertisers (who have been organized into categories based on their products) “bid” for an advertising spot. There is a floor price - a minimum price for the spot, and all bids must exceed that floor price.  This community will be testing the open auction experiment, beginning on November 13, 2024.  For more information or to provide feedback on the experiment, please refer to the post on Meta Stack Exchange.

This reminds me of the Vogons in Hitchhikers Guide through the galaxy: "All the planning charts and d̶e̶m̶o̶l̶i̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ advertising orders have been on display at your local planning department in A̶̶̶l̶̶̶p̶̶̶h̶̶̶a̶̶̶ ̶̶̶C̶̶̶e̶̶̶n̶̶̶t̶̶̶a̶̶̶u̶̶̶r̶̶̶i̶̶̶ Stackexchange headquarters for fifty years of your Earth years. If you can't be bothered to take an interest in local affairs, that's your own problem"

what relevant ads could you possibly show Space Exploration SE?

ads for Starlink? lol

@ErinAnne Ads for Space merch?

@RoryAlsop I want a t-shirt that says "Not An Answer"

Relevant ads could include, for example, online courses...

@Philippe Online courses in what? How would one have an online Space Exploration course? Frankly, I'd imagine, or at least hope, that courses don't exist that can teach people how to build, say, a rocket (or more releastically part of it). That's a great way to get someone who shouldn't to learn how to build a missile.

@Starship on the contrary, you can find full college course lectures on all that published free on Youtube. Missiles aren't hard to build, especially these days.

@ErinAnne Do you think that you could learn to build a rocket/missile off YouTube (provided you didn't work in the industry. maybe say you have the background knowledge of someone who cares a lot about space but it isn't their job.) If so, that's very very worrying.

@Starship on the contrary, I find it greatly encouraging that despite the free and widespread availability of that knowledge, it's newsworthy when people shoot missiles at each other in anger

@ErinAnne Shoot missiles isn't that uncommon when it comes to terror groups. For example tens of thousands of rockets have been shot at Israel in the past 13 ish months. But now I understand how a group of 25 people can learn to build them.

I turned off my ad blocker to look.  Where are the ads?  Did the experiment start?

I haven’t seen any ads yet, but why post an answer asking if the ads are here? It’s like as if you are demanding the Staff to add ads quicker. Do you really want that?

@TheRocketfan I'd like to understand what's going on with the site. I can't stop them from doing whatever they're going to do, but when the things they communicate don't seem to happen, I think it's worth knowing why.

Oh, maybe I do see them now.  Sidebar ads from indeed for random jobs, seems like. Playing the hits.
